# WinHTTPP Conectividad TLS 1.2

Tags: vba, windows10, vb6, windows7

estoy viendo un proyecto .EXE en VB6, en WIN10 no tengo ningún problema funciona correctamente pero en WIN7 tengo el siguiente error [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] esto sale en el en el PUNTO1

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hice lo siguiente comente el PUNTO1 y si funciona  tanto para WIN7 Y 10 pero mi duda va a lo siguiente

- Puede generar un problema si dejo comentando el PUNTO1
- Donde puedo obtener la documentación del WINHTTP, según lo que leí en post de de stackoverflow el OPTION(4) hace que ignore los errores por el SSL

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/winhttprequest

Comment: gracias , pero ahí no esta los valores que tiene el options por ejemplo que significa el option(9)   o el option(4)

Comment: Más que esto no encontré. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winhttp/winhttprequestoption